# integrals exponential functions, and powers

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

How to integrate the following expressions

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{a}e^{-bx}e^{-cx^{d}}dx $$

where a, b, c, d are positive real.

Thanks in advance for both your time and patience

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? Have you tried something?

Comment: Well, this is problematic unless $d=2$.

Comment: Kindly use the comments to respond to users : clicking on "Add a comment" below will help you respond to users. Use @username to address specific users. I request you to search the site using the tool Approach0. I have done so, some search results are [here](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint%20%20x%5Eae%5E%7B-bx%7De%5E%7Bcx%5Ed%7Ddx%24&p=1). Consider supplying more information on why you want to study these integrals or if you have other results to share with appropriate references.

Comment: I would be very surprised if it has an elementary closed form for general $a, b, c, d$. What is the context? Is it really the closed form that you want?